# Serritor Problems

Tags: java, selenium

I´m trying to crawl a dynamic Webpage with Serritor but there is a Problem:

This is my Code:

```
 public class MyCrawler extends BaseCrawler {

    public MyCrawler() {
        String pathToDriver = ".//ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", pathToDriver);
        config.setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());
        config.setFilterOffsiteRequests(true);
        config.addSeedAsString("http://yourspecificsite.com");
        config.setCrawlingStrategy(CrawlingStrategy.DEPTH_FIRST);
        config.setDelayBetweenRequests(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    }

}
```

And this the return:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver
at com.github.peterbencze.serritor.internal.CrawlerConfiguration.<init>(CrawlerConfiguration.java:47)
at com.github.peterbencze.serritor.api.BaseCrawler.<init>(BaseCrawler.java:68)
at serritor_versuch2.MyCrawler.<init>(MyCrawler.java:21)
at serritor_versuch2.run.main(run.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/htmlunit/HtmlUnitDriver
```

Above exception clearly states that HtmlUnitDriver class is not found. If you are using maven, you should probably add maven dependency in your `pom.xml` file.

Not sure, which version are you using but here is the latest version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.52.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using gradle or any other dependency management tool, look accordingly from: [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-htmlunit-driver/2.52.0)

If you are not using any dependency management tool, you should download the jar file and put it in your classpath.